# search using query-string in a var is not working in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am facing a very simple problem, what i give in `find()` if i put it in a `var str;` and pass `find(str)` it doesn't work;

if I search using the the below in mongoose

```
Hospitals.find({ $or: [{treatment:'HYDERABAD'} ,{city:'HYDERABAD'} ]}).

).sort({'city': 1}).exec(function (err, hospitals) {

                if(err){.some code.}

                else{.some code.}

  });
```

search is successful

but if I put the same in a string and pass to **find()**

like this:

```
var mystr;
mystr = "{ $or: [{treatment:'HYDERABAD'} ,{city:'HYDERABAD'} ]}";
 Hospitals.find(mystr).sort({'city': 1}).exec(function (err, hospitals) {
if(err){.some code.}
  else{.some code.}

});
```

it gives this error

```
{ ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got { $or: [{treatment:'HYDERABAD'} ,{city:'HYDERABAD'} ]}

at MongooseError.ObjectParameterError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/objectParameter.js:23:11)

at Query.find (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1424:16)

at Function.find (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1413:13)

at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app.js:1459:27

at callbacks (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)

at param (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)

at pass (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)

at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)

at Object.router (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)

at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)

at Object.handle (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express-sanitizer/lib/express-sanitizer.js:25:5)

at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)

at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5

at invokeCallback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)

at done (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)

at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)

message: 'Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got { $or: [{treatment:\'HYDERABAD\'} ,{city:\'HYDERABAD\'} ]}',

name: 'ObjectParameterError' }
```

Can someone Please help,

Thank you,

Anurag

Comment: Remove double quotes from the string and try. Keep it as object

Answer (score 0):

`Model.find()` take condition parameter as type Object,

by doing,

`mystr = "{ $or: [{treatment:'HYDERABAD'} ,{city:'HYDERABAD'} ]}";`

mystr get converted to string. Because of this when mystr was passed to the `find(mystr)`, it got an error.

you should do :

```
  mystr = { $or: [{treatment:'HYDERABAD'} ,{city:'HYDERABAD'} ]};
```